# How to disable annoying auto go to location while typing in the address bar in Firefox 48+?

Tags: firefox, address-bar, about-config

I've noticed a strange behavior in Firefox since version 48 (maybe it was in the earlier versions too).

When I'm starting to type a domain name in the address bar, sometimes Firefox is trying to guess it and automatically goes to some domain name from the history.

How to turn off that annoying option?

Please, help me and thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this needs a better description, or maybe even a screenshot: I've not seen Firefox make any choice without the user confirming it.

Comment: By "automatically goes to some domain name", do you mean that FF actually loads the site without you pressing "Enter" (this would be very weird) or that it autocompletes a domain in the address bar?

Comment: @lemontree, yes, it loads the site from history without pressing "Enter". This is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I turn off that annoying option?

Here are the instructions:

> **Prevent Firefox from automatically completing URLs**
>
> If you want to turn off the feature that automatically fills in URLs
>   as you type in the location bar, you can change a preference setting
>   in the Firefox Configuration Editor (about:config page). Follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. In the address bar, type "about:config" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    - The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click "I accept the risk!" to continue to the about:config
>        page.
> 2. At the top of the about:config page, type "autoFill" in the Search field (or scroll through the list to find the
>      "browser.urlbar.autoFill" preference).
> 3. Double-click the "browser.urlbar.autoFill" preference to set its value to `false`. (You can then close the about:config page.)

Source [Awesome Bar - Search your Firefox bookmarks, history and tabs from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs#w_prevent-firefox-from-automatically-completing-urls)

Comment: Thank you, but autofill is another option. I'm looking for auto go to location option.